# Include a Start-up that didn't launch on resume if unemployed for a year?

Tags: resume, human-resources, employment-gaps

I worked at the same company for 24 yrs and progressed to a supervisor role over that time.  Once laid off my wife and I looked into starting a mobile medical office to the point of having a business plan and talking to partners but then other elements of her career opened up and we stopped pursuing it.  I then switched to a stay-at-home father role to support her progress.  How should I explain the one year gap in my resume?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Presenting open source development during a resume-gap?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3047/presenting-open-source-development-during-a-resume-gap)  Even though the topic covers open-source instead of startup, it's roughly equivalent.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely I believe its different enough to allow.

Comment: The description of the question seems clear enough  but the title is confusing?? Is it the start-up that you want to explain or the gap when you switched to stay-at-home father role?

Answer (score 8):

In I were in your shoes, I would explain the gap just like you did in the question.

I my opinion, it is not necessary for you to include the startup in your résumé but be ready to explain the gap.

As an hiring manager, your explanation is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I agree if the start up never became an official thing it doesn't make much sense, besides 24 years at one job where he advanced? That's a VERY rare and attractive thing in most markets to find on a resume these days.

Comment: Turned to answer

Comment: I agree that it probably doesn't need to go on a resume, but a cover letter is a great place to include this explanation. Just make sure to pitch it as "this is my experience" and not "this is why there's a gap".

Answer (score 2):

For me, a gap in a resume instantly pushes it towards the reject pile - to go to the next step with gaps, it had better be a pretty good one. Never leave gaps - you might not get an interview to explain them - especially if it appears you are hiding the gaps.

As a potential employer I would value the experience a failed start up gives someone and to leave the off a resume is wrong. To me, "1 Year - Failed startup..."  is a superior resume than virtually any other 1 year of experience -especially for someone with 24 years working for the same company.

At interview time, I would be asking a lot of questions around that, and would be looking to see what you learnt from the experience.

If a company rejects you for putting "Stay at home dad" on your resume, you are probably better off if they do not interview you.